# IntelliJ external AS3 library linkage setting ignored

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, intellij-idea, linkage, swc

I have a big actionscript project with several external libraries added to dependencies tab. To optimize compilation time I decided to create a module that will compile all these libraries to a single swc. And that is something I've encounter problem with as IntelliJ seems to ignore linkage settings for these libraries. I set linkage to 'include' so that my swc will aggregate all the code from external libraries but instead it looks like I always end up with 'merged' linkage mode.

If my swc-module has no additional code, then IntelliJ will refuse to compile it at all because it says that there's nothing to compile. If I create a dummy class that will access some classes from external libraries then it will compile an swc but with only mentioned classes. That's exactly what 'merged' linkage mode is.

[image: example]

I don't know if it is me doing something wrong or it is a bug in IntelliJ but it's definitely a problem. So I decided to start with a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Is your module type set to ActionScript library?

Comment: Yes. I even tried to switch this module to web application, compile it and decompile it back to see what was actually included to swf. Nothing except referenced classes.

Comment: As an application, the compiler will optimize by removing unused classes.  Only library projects with include linkage will persist unreferenced classes.

Comment: Ok, that was incorrect but still problem persists for actionscript library module. I am trying to include several libraries but output swc is only 1.5kb with nothing inside.